# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. in for loop and array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a function like this

```
var playerArray:Array = new Array();

function lockPlayerCards(totalCards) {
    if (totalCards == "all"){
        for (var _loc2:int = 1; _loc2 <= playerArray.length; ++_loc2){
            MovieClip(getChildByName("card" + playerArray[_loc2])).effects.gotoAndStop("block");
            MovieClip(getChildByName("card" + playerArray[_loc2])).btLeft.enabled = false;
            MovieClip(getChildByName("card" + playerArray[_loc2])).btRight.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

but when I call this function

```
lockPlayerCards("all")
```

I have error:
TypeError:

> Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object
>   reference.    at
>   gaple2_fla::MainTimeline/lockPlayerCards()[gaple2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:168]
>     at
>   gaple2_fla::MainTimeline/enterFrameControler()[gaple2_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:533]

Comment: Arrays are numbered from 0, so when `_loc2` becomes equal `playerArray.length` you get a null. Also, BAD MOVE looking up a thing by name and NOT checking result for null.

Comment: _"MainTimeline::frame1:168"_? It helps a lot if you mention which one is **line 168** in your code.

Comment: Why he get -1? I've seen lot wore questions...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this code

```
for (var _loc2:int = 1; _loc2 <= playerArray.length; ++_loc2){
```

use this code

```
for (var _loc2:int = 1; _loc2 < playerArray.length; ++_loc2){
```

remove the `=` button so that it will work